# MAX9924 input signal and bias?

Tags: bias

I'm trying figure out how to connect a [MAX9924](https://www.analog.com/en/products/max9924.html) ("*Variable-Reluctance Sensor Interface with Differential Input and Adaptive Peak Threshold*") to a sensor on a rowing machine.  My knowledge of electronics is about the battery and light bulb level. The sensor is a coil that is next to the flywheel that has 3 magnets in it.  I've attached an image of the output of the coil when the flywheel is spinning at typical speeds.  I expect the maximum voltage of interest is +/- 0.4V. The minimum voltage is shown in the second picture where it's about +/- 50mV.

I'm unclear on what input signal the MAX9924 expects.  Can I connect the sensor as-is?  The datasheet lists:
Input Voltage Range IN+, IN-, -0.3 to VCC+0.3
Specifically I'm wondering about the negative voltage on the input.  The circuits I've looked at the MAX9924 is directly connected to a reluctor that I assume would produce a similar signal to my sensor.

What is the bias?  Can I use the MAX9924 internal bias of 2.5V?  (If I could use the MAX9924 in mode A2 that would simplify the design.)

[image: Typical signal while rowing]

[image: Signal while rower spins down]